# On the convergence of a sequence of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Suppose that $f_n → f$uniformly on some set $E$ and that for each $n$, there
exists $M_n$ such that

$$|f_n(x)| ≤ M\quad\text{for all }n=1,2,3...\text{ and all }x ∈ E.$$

Suppose $g$ is a continuous function on $[-M,M]$.

How to show that $g(f_n(x))$ converges uniformly to $g(f(x))$ on $E$?

Comment: Use [Heine-Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem) to conclude that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[-M,M]$.

Comment: no idea actually! need some more help

Comment: Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[-M,M]$ then there is $\delta>0$ such that for every $r,s\in[-M,M]$ with $|r-s|<\delta$ it will happen that $|g(r)-g(s)|<\epsilon$. Now, since $f_n$ converges uniformly, there is $N$ such that for every $n>N$ and all $x\in E$ you will have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\delta$. Since $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ are both in $[-M,M]$ we can take $r=f_n(x)$ and $s=f(x)$ above, giving $|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and $x\in E$.

Comment: thanks for the help